# Sql queries combine them into 1 .. Help needed

Tags: sql, select, join, subquery, correlated-subquery

```
Select TourDateRange.Detail,                
            (select top 1 TourID from TourDates where TourDateRangeID=TourDateRange.ID)as TourID,
            (select top 1 TourDateRangeID from TourDates where TourDateRangeID=TourDateRange.ID)as TourDateRangeID,
            (select top 1 StartDate from TourDates where TourDateRangeID=TourDateRange.ID)as StartDate,
            (select top 1 StartDate from TourDates where TourDateRangeID=TourDateRange.ID order by ID desc)as EndDate,
            (select top 1 AdultPrice from TourDates where TourDateRangeID=TourDateRange.ID)as AdultPrice,
            (select top 1 ChildPrice from TourDates where TourDateRangeID=TourDateRange.ID)as ChildPrice,
            (select top 1 ID from TourDates where TourDateRangeID=TourDateRange.ID)as TourDatesID
        From TourDateRange
        Where TourDateRange.TourID = @sTourID
        Order By TourDateRange.ID Desc

        Select '' as Detail,@sTourID as TourID,'' as TourDateRangeID,StartDate,EndDate,AdultPrice,ChildPrice,ID as TourDatesID From TourDates where TourID = @sTourID AND TourDateRangeID is Null
```

Help me on this query I want to join both into 1 single query ... means want to take 1 data table behind

Comment: You have a bigger problem - you're using `TOP 1` without an `ORDER BY`, which means that which value is returned is undefined - they're not guaranteed to be from the same row.  That part at least looks like a classic [tag:greatest-n-per-group] problem.  Otherwise, presumably you could `UNION` the two queries together...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understood well from your queries, you needed to take into the result tours that "have" TourDateRange" plus the ones that do not have one.

I hope this would give you the results needed:

```
Select 
    ISNULL(TourDateRange.Detail, '') AS Detail,                
    TourDates.TourID,
    ISNULL(TourDates.TourDateRangeID, '') AS TourDateRangeID,
    MIN(TourDates.StartDate) AS MinStartDate,
    MAX(TourDates.EndDate) AS MaxEndDate,
    TourDates.AdultPrice,
    TourDates.ChildPrice,
    MAX(TourDates.ID) as MaxTourDatesID
From 
    TourDates 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN TourDateRange
        ON TourDates.TourDateRangeID = TourDateRange.ID
Where 
    TourDates.TourID = @sTourID
GROUP BY
    ISNULL(TourDateRange.Detail, '') ,                
    TourDates.TourID,
    ISNULL(TourDates.TourDateRangeID, '') ,
    TourDates.AdultPrice,
    TourDates.ChildPrice,
Order by
    TourDateRangeID
```

Comment: First of all thanks for your reply ... below image can define best .please check it out ![Valid XHTML](https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/horoe3X6sm0LqR4lr7lBJ6JT6QotLA0hXGS5Jfdtmw=w551-h207-p-no)

Comment: Could you tell me what about (hypothetical) situation shown on this excel sheet: **https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15NoQn3-eKt0LKXXmCn0VyIX4GiJ9VQMrZzEjGHkFY6I/edit#gid=0** (rows marked as yellow and cell text in red)? How should the result look like then? I don't know if it could happen in your model, but worth asking.

Comment: Thank you very much friend it solved my problem.. :) seems to be I have to learn more .......

Comment: I'm really glad I could help. I think everyone has to learn instantly... :)